# Rails 5 - Store Active Storage files in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

We have an existing Rails 5.2.3 project with file uploads implemented in various places. Active Storage is configured to store them on disk in the /storage directory, but there is now a requirement that we store files in a database table instead.

Is it possible to configure Active Storage to store files in a database table? I've had a look through the docs and I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do that...

Found this [gem](https://github.com/TitovDigital/activestorage-database-service) for Active Storage.

You can also do it with [Refile](https://github.com/krists/refile-postgres) if you are using postgres as db

Answer (score 1):

I've using another [gem](https://github.com/lsylvester/active_storage-postgresql). For small files it's working great.